# how to auto fill value with jquery from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some problem, this is my case, i have two input tag
tag input one

```
<input type="text" name="samaccountname" id="samaccountname" />
```

tag input two

```
<input type="text" name="question" id="question" readonly />
```

and json object such as :

```
[{"samaccountname":"19000","question":"Your Birthday"},{"samaccountname":"19100","question":"Your Car Brand"}];
```

how to auto fill the no 2 tag input (question) if no 1 tag input (samaccountname) is same value with my json object, with jquery with $.each?

Comment: Show full code. We need to see the JS as well

Comment: Have your tried anything? Show us your code please.

Comment: Fill the second input with what?

Comment: Actually, i havent made now, because am newbie. I just want to know how to solve my case with jquery, @PartharajDeb

Comment: those json object you want to put in your input field via dropdown, I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var mJson = [{"samaccountname":"19000","question":"Your Birthday"},{"samaccountname":"19100","question":"Your Car Brand"}];

    $("#samaccountname").keyup(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.each(mJson, function(i,v){
            if(id == v.samaccountname){
                $("#question").val(v.question);
                return false; // breaks the loop
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: thank for advice, but i doesnt work. This my last case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221539/get-params-from-bootstrap-modal-to-input-field/43221695?noredirect=1#comment73514293_43221695

then i want to combine my last with my new case, so if i have value on the input tag one (samaccountname), the two tag input (question) can be autofill with it. 

note: tag one (samaccountname) is readonly attrribut input

Comment: I did as you expected. While you start typing on `(samaccountname)` input, it'll loop through the object and match the inputted value with id and will set the question to the `(question)` input, whatever it is readonly or not.

Comment: sorry, your code is work. how to call myjson with url, cause i pass to the somepage for my json, this is my code

`function urlListUser(uripath, slice_a, slice_b){
    var uri = $(location).attr('href').slice(slice_a, slice_b);
    var uridata = uri + uripath;
    
    return uridata;
}`

Comment: and 
`$(document).ready(function(){
    var mJson = urlListUser('listuser',0,-10); //ex: http://localhost/ldpan/listuser
    //var mJson = [{"samaccountname":"19000","question":"Your Birthday"},{"samaccountname":"19100","question":"Your Car Brand"}];
    $("#samaccountname").keyup(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.each(mJson, function(i,v){
            if(id == v.samaccountname){
                $("#question").val(v.question);
            }
            console.log(v.question);
        });
    });
});`

Comment: Your code is not clear in the comment. As I guess you are trying to fetch the json from some url of you server, in this case you may need to use ajax. You may study about that here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: If this answer was helpful you should `Accept` it as your support.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var uri = urlListUser('listuser',0,-10);
    $("#samaccountname").keyup(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: uri,
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(i,v){
                    if(id == v.nik){
                        $("#question").val(v.question);
                    }
                    console.log(v.question);
                });
            } 
        });    
    });
});
```